# How is the RRO of the RSVP "RESV" message populated?

Tags: rsvp

Let's say, that router `r1` sends a RSVP "PATH" message to router `r4` through routers `r2` and `r3`. `r4` replies with "RESV" message and when received by `r1`, then the RRO of "RESV" message includes the addresses of the interfaces which "PATH" message was received on. My initial thought was that the RRO of "PATH" message is copied to the RRO of the "RESV" message, but this is not the case. Am I correct, that each router which received the "PATH" message kept track of the IP of the interface where the "PATH" message was received on and once the router saw the corresponding "RESV" message, then the address was put into the RRO of the "RESV" message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. I'll support my statements with excerpts from [RFC3209](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3209#section-4.4.3) (Section 4.4.3 - Processing RRO)

1. Using your example node `r1` will send a PATH message toward `r2` with its own IP address (i.e. the egress interface IP) in the RRO.

> Typically, a node initiates an RSVP session by adding the RRO to the
> Path message.  The initial RRO contains only one subobject - the
> sender's IP addresses.

2. Then `r2` will receive the PATH message, store it in its local path state, append its own address in the RRO of a new PATH message to be sent toward `r3`.

> When a Path message containing an RRO is received by an intermediate
> router, the router stores a copy of it in the Path State Block.  The
> RRO is then used in the next Path refresh event for formatting Path
> messages.  When a new Path message is to be sent, the router adds a
> new subobject to the RRO and appends the resulting RRO to the Path
> message before transmission.

3. The same process will occur between `r3` and `r4`.

Now `r4` has the fully constructed RRO between `r1` and itself.

As for the RESV messages it basically works the same in the reverse direction as they traverse from `r4` back to `r1`.

> When the destination node of an RSVP session receives a Path message
> with an RRO, this indicates that the sender node needs route
> recording.  The destination node initiates the RRO process by adding
> an RRO to Resv messages.  The processing mirrors that of the Path
> messages.  The only difference is that the RRO in a Resv message
> records the path information in the reverse direction.

Comment: Thanks! So as I understand, for example the RRO seen in the output of `show mpls lsp name r1->r4 detail ingress` executed in Juniper router named `r1` shows the RRO of the RESV message. What if the RESV message took a different path from `r4` to `r1` than the initial PATH message from `r1` to `r4`? This would give a false impression of the actual traffic path for a one executing the `show mpls lsp name r1->r4 detail ingress` command. Or perhaps the RESV message always follows the path of the PATH message?

Comment: I can imagine cases where you have asymmetric IGP metrics on either side of an interface, but probably not a good idea to do that.